# How to Send Variables from Java class to PHP script?

Tags: java, php, mysql

So, I'm trying to recreate an older PHP program of mine partially in Java however I've hit a roadblock in my code. No matter what I try to do, I can't seem to send information from my Java class to my PHP script. The PHP script is hosted on an online server, while my Java class is on a client machine.
My code goes as following:

```
            String query = SearchTextBox.getText();

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/wc_wca?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","pass" );
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE id = ?";        
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, query);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    try{
                    URL url = new URL("http://worldcubers.com/setup/index.php");
                    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                    String name = rs.getString("name");
                    String id = rs.getString("id");
                    // activate the output
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    PrintStream printstream = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
                    // send your parameters to your site
                    printstream.print("&name=" + name);
                    printstream.print("&id=" + id);

                    // we have to get the input stream in order to actually send the request
                    con.getInputStream();

                    // close the print stream
                    ps.close();
                    }           
                    catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                    initAndShowGUI();
                    this.dispose(); //to close the current jframe
                }
```

In the PHP script, the lines that access the variables are the following:

```
$s = $_SESSION['name'];
$q = $_SESSION['id'];
```

I've tried many different articles here on StackOverflow, but to no avail, no matter what I try, I can't seem to send the name & id variables to the PHP script.

Comment: `ps.close();` doesn't close the print stream...

Comment: What does it do, then?

Comment: Take another look and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I think its high time you to start to think of using [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp) to fix the problem you are facing
Also check here [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java?rq=1)

I am using JSON to send variables back and forth for android app. I think the same can apply here.

Then think of using **$_POST** or **$_GET** but not *$_SESSION*

Comment: That helps with reading JSON, but how exactly would I write files from a client side Java app to a server hosted PHP script? Also, I only want to send 2 variables, is this  the most optimal method for sending only 2 variables to the server?